# Finding all asp.net elements with specific suffix using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to find all asp.net elements with a suffix _val, if so what is the syntax? (I must use the .ClientID and cant use Static Client ID)

I know we can typically use

```
$('div[id$="_val"]')
```

And I know how to select individual elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myDomElement = document.getElementById("panel_validate_field")
    $(myDomElement).find("#<%=txt_Surname_val.ClientID%>").change(function() {
        // do my validation check
    });
});
```

However the former does not work with the asp.net controls, I assume this has something to do with the unique client id. Is there any way I can combine these two methods ? I would like to avoid having to iterate through all my panels elements as not all of them require the validation re-correction.

Comment: if you want to target multiple elements, why not just use a class?

Comment: why not just give all fields you want to target  the same class (as well as the others that style it) - you aren't limited to using just one class per element.  Also, classes don't necessarily have to apply a style - they can be used just so that js can target them (which can improve performance as they are more efficient than attribute selectors)

Comment: I'm not even sure how to select via class when there are multiple classes.

Comment: same way you do when there is one class - http://jsfiddle.net/amvc5h0z/

Comment: doesn't seem to work I'm using `$(myDomElement).find(".val").on('change keyup paste',function()` but its not finding anything, as I assume its not finding the unique client id ? I can't use client mode static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok silly blunder of mine, the correct form is simply (overcomplicating in my head)

```
$(myDomElement).find('[id$=_val]')
```